# Improving an LSTM models fit to a datasets noise

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am a data analyst trying to improve my knowledge with machine learning.

I've completed a model for a timeseries dataset, where each point is 1 day apart, with no gaps. The specific model type that I have attempted is a multi-layered auto-regression bi-directional LSTM using tensorflow's keras, see model specific code below:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(
            units = 128,
            input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]),
            return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(
            units = 64,
            input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]),
            return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(
            units = 32,
            input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]),
            return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(
            units = 16,
            input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]),
            return_sequences=False)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate = 0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adam')
history = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    epochs = 100,
    batch_size = 128,
    validation_split = 0.2,
    shuffle = False
) 
print(model.summary())
```

I've been told that this is likely overkill for this specific learning task by a superior member of staff, but wanted to add it for full transparency.
See summary below:

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 bidirectional (Bidirectiona  (None, 50, 256)          133120
 l)

 bidirectional_1 (Bidirectio  (None, 50, 128)          164352
 nal)

 bidirectional_2 (Bidirectio  (None, 50, 64)           41216
 nal)

 bidirectional_3 (Bidirectio  (None, 32)               10368
 nal)

 dense (Dense)               (None, 16)                528

 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 16)                0

 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 17

=================================================================
Total params: 349,601
Trainable params: 349,601
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The model reports the loss values (after 100 epochs, using Mean Squared Error):

> loss: 0.0040 - val_loss: 0.0050 (Overfit)

With an RMSE derived with: `math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train,train_predict))` and `math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,test_predict))` with `sklearn.metrics` and the built in function `mean_squared_error` from the aforementioned package.

> Train RMSE:  28.795422522129595

> Test RMSE:  34.17014386085355

And for a graphical representation:
[image]
[image]

To which I finally arrive at my question; how do I better fit my model to more closely represent the noise within the data, as this is what I believe to be causing the high RMSE values.
I have looked into attention mechanisms, in the hopes that I might be able to highlight specific peaks and troughs within the data, but it seems that these are best used with image/text prediction oriented models. I could try training over more epochs, but the model is already slightly overfit, so this would exasperate this particular issue further.

I understand this is a fairly open ended question but I have best tried to "show my working", and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does look like a massive overkill for the task. Start by reducing the number of LSTM layers and adding dropout in between the LSTM layers and within each LSTM.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've dropped it down to 2 LSTM layers, each with 64 neurons each, a dropout and recurrent_dropout of 0.5, with a dropout layer in between the two LSTM layers again at 0.5, and currently re-training

Answer (score 0):

You've only got that signal as input and you're trying to predict it's values? remember that it's quite possible that the noise is effectively just noise and there's no way to predict it just from that data.

Attention doesn't sound like it would be helpful unless you have some reason to think that looking way back at other time-steps could help you predict what's happening *now*. And a lot of systems have the Markov property: If you know the state now, nothing from the history leading there matters.

The signal has clear periodicity, you can make it easier for the model to learn that by including sin & cos features like I do for the time of day and time of year here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

You could try other features too, like a diff or an EMA, or some of those ARIMA style features. But fundamentally if it is effectively noise better features won't help, they'll only help you train to the same error level faster.